# How 2 populate Outlook sendmail hyperlink adress with saved as worksheet so when hyperlink is clicked in sent email it opens the saved sheet or folder

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

Below is my original code that when run in Excel it saves a copy of the active document and sends an email with said document attached. The email code below currently includes a hyperlink to a generic folder. The problem with the hyperlink is that it is currently specific to the address that is "hard" typed in that line of code and I would like the hyperlink to be custom populated in one of two ways below.

**Update:** Issue is solved with code as seen under two options below.

**First and preferred option** would be to create a hyperlink that **directly opens** the SAVED file (not attached file).
**Code for this is** <a href=""file:" & MyFileDest & """>here.

**Second option** would be a hyperlink that opens the actual **folder** that the SAVED file (not attached file) is in.
**Code for this is** <a href=""file:" & fileSaveName & """>here.

## Below is original code

```
'Establish file name and save location using data from Form

    Dim MyFile, MyFileDest, MyFileName As String
    
    MyFile = ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("F5").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("E5").Value & " (" & ActiveSheet.Range("AB8").Value & ")" & ".xlsm"
    MyFileDest = "\\camawsis03\Team Center\" & ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & " " & "Rework Forms\"
    MyFileName = MyFileDest & MyFile
    
'Check if folder exist, if not create folder

    If Dir(MyFileDest, vbDirectory) <> vbNullString Then
    'MsgBox "Folder exists"
    Else
    
    MkDir "\\camawsis03\Team Center\" & ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & " " & "Rework Forms"
    End If


'Save to location and include pop-up Save As window

    Dim NewName As Variant
    Dim fileSaveName As Variant
    
    NewName = MyFileName
    fileSaveName = Application.GetSaveAsFilename(InitialFileName:=NewName, fileFilter:="Excel Files (*.xlsm), *.xlsm")

    If fileSaveName <> False Then
    ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs fileSaveName
    'MsgBox "File saved to: " & fileSaveName
    End If

    
'Email with attached workbook.

    Set OutlookApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
    Set SendMail = OutlookApp.CreateItem(0)
    Dim JobDesc As String
    Dim Rootcause As String
    JobDesc = ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("F5").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("E5").Value
    Rootcause = ActiveSheet.Range("N5").Value & " - " & ActiveSheet.Range("N6").Value & " - " & ActiveSheet.Range("N7").Value
    
    SourceFile = ThisWorkbook.FullName
    SendMail.Attachments.Add SourceFile

    SendMail.Subject = ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("F5").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("E5").Value & " " & "Rework" & " " & "(" & ActiveSheet.Range("AB8").Value & ")"
    SendMail.To = Leaderemail & ";" & ActiveSheet.Range("AC5").Value
    SendMail.CC = ActiveSheet.Range("AC6").Value & "; mcatalano@windsormoldgroup.com>"
    'Use SendMail.htmlBody for bold,unbold <b>,</b>= & new line=<br>
    SendMail.htmlBody = "Please find attached Rework Form for " & JobDesc & "." & " " & "Steel is located in" & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("E7").Value & "." & "<br><br>" _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & WorkReqdComment & "<br><br>" _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & PrepReqdComment & "<br><br>" _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "The attached is for notification only. Please reference master saved <a href=""\\camawsis03\Team Center\Rework Forms"">here.</a>"
    
    SendMail.Display 'displays email window
    'Use SendMail.Send to send without display.
    
    With Application
    .EnableEvents = True
    .ScreenUpdating = True
    End With
    
    Set SendMail = Nothing
    Set OutlookApp = Nothing
    
    ActiveWorkbook.Close savechanges:=False

End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code posted? Have you tried running the code under the debugger attached?

Comment: `"Please reference master saved <a href=""file:" & MyFileDest & """>here.</a>"`

Comment: What is the actual value passed to the message body? Does the file location make sense on the recipient side?

Comment: @Eugene Astafiev -  The actual value of the hyperlink that is generated in email is this \\camawsis03\Team Center\2222\2222 Rework Forms\. This is the correct folder of my target file. This folder location has been tested and is useable by all recipients. Although I would rather have the hyperlink open the actual target file which is the file that is saved off in above code. Any help to accomplish that is appreciated. Also, thank you for cleaning up my code in this post.

Comment: @Tim Williams - Thank you. Your code works to create custom hyperlink to the folder that my target file is in as in option 2 of my post. Although how might I make the hyperlink open the actual target file and not the folder as in option 1 of my post? Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try `"Please reference master saved <a href=""file:" & fileSaveName & """>here.</a>"` ?

Comment: @Tim Williams - I tried <a href=""file:" & fileSaveName & """>here.</a> just now and it works beautifully, I knew I was close but didn't understand the code 100% so figured I'd save myself 4 hours and ask the community. I'll update my code in this post with the code that works for the two above options. How do I give you an upvote?

Comment: I will post an answer

Comment: Glad that my question helped to figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

This should work:

```
SendMail.htmlBody = "Please find attached Rework Form for " & _
     JobDesc & "." & " " & "Steel is located in" & " " & _
     ActiveSheet.Range("E7").Value & "." & "<br><br>" _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & WorkReqdComment & "<br><br>" _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & PrepReqdComment & "<br><br>" _
    & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "The attached is for notification only. " _
    & "Please reference master saved <a href='file:" & fileSaveName  & "'>here.</a>"
```

Answer (score 0):

> The actual value of the hyperlink that is generated in email is this \camawsis03\Team Center\2222\2222 Rework Forms. This is the correct folder of my target file.

You need to reference a file with a file path in the hyperlink, not only the folder location if you want to open the file.

So, instead of the following folder path:

```
"The attached is for notification only. Please reference master saved <a href=""\\camawsis03\Team Center\Rework Forms"">here.</a>"
```

You need to specify the file path:

```
Dim MyFile, MyFileDest, MyFileName As String
    
    MyFile = ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("F5").Value & " " & ActiveSheet.Range("E5").Value & " (" & ActiveSheet.Range("AB8").Value & ")" & ".xlsm"
    MyFileDest = "\\camawsis03\Team Center\" & ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & "\" & ActiveSheet.Range("B5").Value & " " & "Rework Forms\"
    MyFileName = MyFileDest & MyFile

"The attached is for notification only. Please reference master saved <a href=" & MyFileName & ">here.</a>"
```